EF Core migration for schema based table creation in multi-tenant ASP.NET Core application
I am trying to create tenant-specific schema table for multi-tenant application. Something like below
CREATE SCHEMA Tenant1;

CREATE TABLE Tenant1.Customers 
(
    CustomerId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(100),
    Email NVARCHAR(100),
    Phone NVARCHAR(15)
);

CREATE SCHEMA Tenant2;

CREATE TABLE Tenant2.Customers 
(
    CustomerId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(100),
    Email NVARCHAR(100),
    Phone NVARCHAR(15)
);

DbContext:
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _schema;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, string schema)
        : base(options)
    {
        _schema = schema ?? "default_schema";
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        _schema = "default_schema";
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(_schema);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

I have two entities:
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive => true;
}

public class Tenant
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Schema { get; set; }
}

program.cs:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(optins =>
{
    optins.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("postgresConnection"));
});
builder.Services.AddScoped<TenantDbContextFactory>();

// Seed initial data
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    await DataSeeder.SeedAsync(dbContext);
}

// Apply migrations for each tenant's schema
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    var dbContextFactory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TenantDbContextFactory>();
    var tenants = await dbContext.Tenants.ToListAsync();

    foreach (var tenant in tenants)
    {
        var tenantContext = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(tenant.Schema);
        await tenantContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
    }
}

However, the tables are created in DEFAULT_SCHEMA only. The tenant specific schema is not created.
Factory method:
public sealed class TenantDbContextFactory
{
    private readonly DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> _options;

    public TenantDbContextFactory(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string schema)
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext(_options, schema);
    }
}


Multi-tenancy docs. Multiple schemas is not directly supported by EF Core and is not a recommended solution. If you still decide to do it this way, you will have to manually adjust the migration files, duplicating the SQL code for creating tables and other things for all schemas in them.

You need to label id with [Key] : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations

@AlexanderPetrov In PostgreSQL a Schema is effectively a Database compared to SQL Server, rather than MSSQL's schema, so it should work, though I suspect the OP will need to rely on the DbContextFactory rather than the scoped DbContext service.

The DbContexts that are created in tenant loop is not registered as you did in the beginning :
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(optins =>
{
    optins.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("postgresConnection"));
});

I am not sure if creating db contexts dynamically works.
